# Rules for id ,name and class attribute in HTML5

Tags: html, tagname

What are the rules for naming the id,class,name attributes and tag names in HTML5?Is there any difference from previous HTML standard?

Answer (score 1):

No changes in ID and class. You can still use any UTF8 characters to set ID and class attributes. Remember do use the same ID only once in your document.

For custom tag-attributes, they introduced the family of data-* attributes, where you can append any custom data to your elements (in string form).

Thats all - as far as I know.